# nHibernate count on unmapped entity

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, hql

Using nHibernate 2.

In our system we have a table that stores records which may point to any of the other tables in the system, as well as some additional fields. e.g.

```
class PointerTable
{
    public int ID;
    public string ObjectName;
    public int RecordID;
    ... additional fields
}
```

The ObjectName and RecordID fields point to the name of another table in the system, and the ID of the record in that table that this record points to. There are no relationships between this table and the other tables in the system.

I need to be able to join to this table when I retrieve records from the other tables in the system, as I need to determine if a table has any records in PointerTable that point to it. i.e. get the count of the records in the PointerTable for this record.

I've tried to do this in HQL:

```
select a.ID, e.Field1, a.Field2, a.Field3,
            count(select * 
             from PointerTable p
             where p.ObjectName = "Table1"
               and p.RecordID = a.ID)
from Table1 a 
where a.ParentTable.ID = :ID
```

I've also looked into putting a mapping into the XML configuration files for all the entities in the system which will be pointed to by this table. So I could have a collection of PointerTable records in each of my other entities. Though I'm not sure if this is possible. I can't find how to set the mapping to map on 2 fields rather than the primary key.

Something like:

```
<bag name="PointerRecords" table="PointerTable" lazy="true" inverse="true">      
     <key>
         <column name="ThisEntityID" />
         <column name="ObjectName" />  ?? Hard coded
    </key>
    <one-to-many class="PointerTable" not-found="ignore"/>      
</bag>
```

Is this even possible?

Basically all I'm trying to do is the following SQL query. But ideally we'd like to do this through HQL or mappings.

SQL

```
select a.ID, e.Field1, a.Field2, a.Field3, Count(d.ID)
from Table1 a 
inner join Table2 e on a.ParentID=e.ID
left outer join PointerTable d on d.ObjectName = 'Table1' and d.RecordID = a.ID
where c.ID = @ID
group by a.ID, e.Field1, a.Field2, a.Field3
```

Comment: your HQL seems to be in order, apart from not having a 'group by' section. what exactly isn't working? are you getting an exception? wrong results?

Comment: As it is, I get a NHibernate.QueryException exception "undefined alias or unknown mapping: d"
If i remove the alias, the SQL generated is incorrect (...count_big(select*from PointerTable where ObjectName="Table1" and RecordID=a.ID) as x1_0_)...) rather than something like SELECT(COUNT(*) FROM PointerTable WHERE ...)  and I get a SqlClient.SqlException exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the idea here would be to map this collection with a where clause

using fluentmapping:

```
public SomeEntityMap(){
    Table("SomeTable");

    HasMany(x => x.PointerRecords)
        .Table("PointerTable")
        .KeyColumn("ThisEntityID")
        .Where("ObjectName = 'SomeTable'")
}
```

Begin Edit

using xml-mapping

```
<bag name="PointerRecords" table="PointerTable" lazy="true" inverse="true" where ="ObjectName = 'SomeTable'">
    <key column="ThisEntityID"/>
    <one-to-many class="PointerTable" not-found="ignore"/>
</bag>
```

End Edit

and query like

```
object[] results = session.CreateCriteria<SomeEntity>()
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Id", id))
    .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
        .Add(Projections.Property("Field1"))
        ...
        .Add(Projections.Count("PointerRecords")));
    .List()
```

or

```
var entities = session.CreateCriteria<SomeEntity>()
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Id", id)
    .SetFetchMode("PointerRecords", NHibernate.FetchMode.Eager)
    .List<SomeEntity>();

entities[0].PointerRecords.Count
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Firo, but we are not using fluent nhibernate.

Comment: @matt i added the xml mapping

Comment: excellent! thanks that worked nicely.
Got the HQL working now with a PointerRecords.size with a group by.
Also added the access=”none” attribute so I don't have to add the collection to the entity object (although we may wish to add it anyway now that this mapping is possible). Many thanks.